# Windows 2003 Server boot stops on DHCP

Tags: boot, windows-server-2003

Whenever I try to boot my Windows 2003 Server (happened after a power outage), it spins (hangs) with DHCP on the monitor.

I rebooted several times and checked the configuration, but nothing seems wrong. I am unable to get to Active Directory or any Administrative tool as the boot process does not get that far.

Help, please?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it is trying to boot from a network location. This can happen due to two things. Either when the pc booted previously, there was no network cable attached to it, or it was not configured to check for Boot from Lan while it is now. Secondly, the boot from lan might be the second option and it can't load from the harddrive because the windows install has gone corrupted.

So go into the bios, and look into the boot order of the devices attached. Set the harddrive as first boot device, and make sure that boot form network comes after that. If it still happens, your installation has gone bad and you'll need to reinstall the server.